# Python Tkinter Code- TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter, project, calculator, tkinter-button

I have ensured the button names do not resemble any function yet this error still shows when i try to use trigonometric or any log/other functions imported from math. I am building a scientific calculator, and while i am successfully able to add/subt/mult/div and use brackets and decimal points, calling math functions like sin cos tan shows me TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable

Comment: Change `b=operator.widget()` to `b=operator.widget`.

Comment: one more doubt though, when i try to use pi/e it shows could not convert string to float: ' '   Snippet of that part i've added in main Q

Comment: `no=float(no)` expects `no` to be a string of valid float number.  So check whether `no` is an empty string or not, if it is an empty string, don't call `no=float(no)`.